# XNA - Newly Installed Font not working?

Tags: c#, fonts, xna, spritefont

So recently I installed a new font (.ttf) to my computer so that I can utilize it in my XNA game. It is the proper type of font, and I am spelling it correctly, but XNA cannot find it. Any ideas on what may be causing this?

This is the error: The font family "Bloody" could not be found. Please ensure the requested font is installed, and is a TrueType or OpenType font.

But this font is installed, spelt properly, and is a TrueType font.

Comment: check this font is some other soft: word etc... is it available there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to restart visual studio in order for it to recognize the newly installed fonts.

Next, make sure you use the exact spelling of the font name, as it is shown under your installed fonts directory (typically C:\Windows\Fonts)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know I needed to restart it to recognize new fonts.